# Framework causing crash (swift)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoapods

I am using the ReachabilitySwift framework (installed via Cocoapods) and it works perfectly on the Simulator.  If I try to run directly on the device it crashes immediately.  I have the following error in the log each time:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Reason: DYLD, Filesystem Sandbox | (terminated at launch; ignore backtrace) | Library: @rpath/ReachabilitySwift.framework/ReachabilitySwift | Referenced from: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/0B099F11-558A-4B1D-BEAE-15A1AF8C0BD5/com.gavinb.app.app/com.gavinb.app
Triggered by Thread:  0
```

I've removed ReachabilitySwift and re-added.  I am not even importing into any of my Swift files.

Are there any other steps I can take to stop this on device?

Comment: Have you tried cleaning as well as removing all those magical directories (DerivedData)?

Comment: Thanks, just tried cleaning again and finding / deleting DerivedData, but get same issue

Answer (score 1):

Are you adding `use_frameworks!` to your podfile?

```
use_frameworks! 
platform :ios, '8.0'

pod 'ThePod'
```

Comment: Hi, yes thats included in my Pod file.  I've just removed ReachabilitySwift from the project and the issue then jumps to the next pod file, in this instance Realm.  In my Error I notice it refers to **com.gavinb.app.app** but in my project its all setup as com.gavinb.app

Comment: Do you have any exception breakpoints. Go to Exceptions tab and 'Add Exception Breakpoint' using the + at the bottom left corner if not

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've added a break point but it never triggers.  I assume its something in the project settings causing the issue as if I transpose my files from the project to a new project I don't get the issue.  I think I will just do the little bit of work involved to get this new project setup and working. Thanks for the help though